# Binding a collectionviewsource in datagrid celltemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I've got a thorny problem and I'm hoping you can help. I'm creating a datagrid which involves dynamically creating columns. Here's some pseudocode for my classes:

```
GameLibrary
    ObservableCollection<Game> Games

Game
    ObservableCollection<CustomField> CustomFields

Customfield
    ObservableCollection<string> Values
```

The datagrid is bound to a CollectionViewSource that uses GameLibrary.Games as its Source. The datagrid displays the other properties from Game in each row as I've set up the columns, and then I've got it dynamically created a column for each CustomField in CustomFields and display the relevant CustomField's Values in an itemscontrol in the cell.

This all works great, no problem. Now, though, I'm wanting to sort the Values alphabetically to display. I know best practice for this is using a CollectionViewSource, and I have managed to get one set up, attached to the DataTemplate and displaying in the itemscontrol - but it only works if, as a test, I set the CVS's source to be something external to the datagrid. This displays, but of course it displays the same thing in every row.

How do I bind the DataTemplate's CVS to something in the current row of the table? It's easy enough when not using the CVS, because I can use the binding's Path and just say "CustomFields[i].Values", but I don't know how that translates across to the CVS Source.

Here's what I have now, which works great:

```
            FrameworkElementFactory listbox = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ItemsControl));
            Binding b = new Binding();
            string pathb = "CustomFields[" + i + "].Values";
            b.Path = new PropertyPath(pathb);
            b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            b.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
            listbox.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, b);
            listbox.SetValue(ItemsControl.PaddingProperty, new Thickness(5));
            dock.AppendChild(listbox);

            DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate { VisualTree = dock };
            dt.Seal();
            newcolumn.CellTemplate = dt;
            gameDataDisplay.Columns.Add(newcolumn);
```

And here's what I want:

```
            DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate { VisualTree = dock };

            CollectionViewSource listboxCVS = new CollectionViewSource();
            SortDescription listboxsortDescription = new SortDescription(".", ListSortDirection.Ascending);
            listboxCVS.SortDescriptions.Add(listboxsortDescription);
            listboxCVS.Source = SOMETHING HERE BUT I DONT KNOW WHAT;
            dt.Resources.Add("customCVS" + i, listboxCVS);

            FrameworkElementFactory listbox = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ItemsControl));
            Binding b = new Binding();
            b.Source = listboxCVS;
            listbox.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, b);
            listbox.SetValue(ItemsControl.PaddingProperty, new Thickness(5));
            dock.AppendChild(listbox);

            dt.Seal();
            newcolumn.CellTemplate = dt;
            gameDataDisplay.Columns.Add(newcolumn);
```

I've also tried instead of using a CVS binding to a property in CustomFields that returns a sorted list of the Values and that displays fine, but I know it's not best practice and it doesn't update until you scroll the item offscreen and back, so I think that's a dead end.

Thank you for any help you can offer,

Tom.

PS: The ObservableCollections here aren't strictly ObservableCollections, they're a derived class with a couple extra methods, but they act exactly the same for all practical purposes. Just mentioning here for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this a different way. Rather than creating a new datatemplate programmatically for each custom column, I defined a datatemplate in the window's resources then used a ContentPresenter to fill in the bindings.

XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="customfieldtemplate">
    <DockPanel x:Name="customfieldHolder" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <DockPanel.Resources>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="customfieldview" x:Name="customfieldview" Source="{Binding Values}">
                <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                    <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="."/>
                </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            </CollectionViewSource>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="customfieldsview" x:Name="customfieldsview" Source="{Binding PossibleValues}">
                <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                    <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="."/>
                </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            </CollectionViewSource>
        </DockPanel.Resources>

        <customcontrols:MultiComboBox Width="17" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,0" ShowText="False" x:Name="customfieldMiniCombo" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource customfieldsview}}" SelectedItems="{Binding Values}" SelectionMode="Multiple" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.TextBox.Border}" Background="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ThemeBackground}" Foreground="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.Text}"/>

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource customfieldview}}" Padding="5"/>
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Codebehind:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < maindatafile.CurrentGameLibrary.CustomFields.Count; i++)
        {
            CustomColumn newcolumn = new CustomColumn();
            newcolumn.Header = maindatafile.CurrentGameLibrary.CustomFields[i].Name;

            gameDataDisplay.Columns.Add(newcolumn);

            var template = FindResource("customfieldtemplate");
            FrameworkElementFactory factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ContentPresenter));
            factory.SetValue(ContentPresenter.ContentTemplateProperty, template);

            Binding newBinding = new Binding("CustomFields[" + i + "]");
            newBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            newBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;

            factory.SetBinding(ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, newBinding);

            DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate { VisualTree = factory };

            newcolumn.CellTemplate = dt;
        }
```

The multicombobox user control (found [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45782/A-WPF-Combo-Box-with-Multiple-Selection)) in the template contains an "allowed" set of values to add to or remove from the observablecollection. Its ItemsSource is another property in CustomField, whose getter returns the list of allowable values for that CustomField. The multicombobox's SelectedItems property uses the same binding as the ItemsControl.

End result? The cell displays the list of values in the appropriate CustomField, with a lil dropdown button next to it. That dropdown contains all the possible values for that field, with the ones currently in the list selected. The list updates live as you select and deselect values in this combobox, and also updates live when those values are changed in other parts of the program.